# Programmatically make a dojo datagrid cell span multiple columns

Tags: javascript, html, datagrid, dojo, html-table

I want to create a grid that looks something like this:

```
----------------------------------
| Header 1 | Header 2 | Header 3 |
----------------------------------
| Cell 1.1 | Cell 1.2 | Cell 1.3 |
----------------------------------
| Cell 2.1            | Cell 2.3 |
----------------------------------
| Cell 3.1 | Cell 3.2 | Cell 3.3 |
----------------------------------
```

I thought I could do something like this:

```
col1Formatter = function(data,row,cell) {
  if (row==2)
    cell.markup = "<td span=2>Cell2.1</td>";
};

col2Formatter = function(data,row,cell) {
  if (row==2)
    cell.markup = "";
};
```

But I can't find any documentation on how to manipulate the cell's DOM from within a formatter.

Answer (score 1):

As any table you can set it by `colspan` property.

So... examples are giants:

```js
 dojo.require("dijit.dijit");
 dojo.require("dojox.layout.TableContainer");
 dojo.require("dijit.form.TextBox");
 dojo.require("dijit.form.CheckBox");
 dojo.require("dijit.form.Textarea");
```

```css
.labelsAndValues-labelCell {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
.labelsAndValues-valueCell {
  padding-left: 20px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<script type='text/javascript' src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js' data-dojo-config="parseOnLoad:true, async:'legacyAsync'"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/normalize.css">


<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">


<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">



<script type='text/javascript' src="http://amd.egoworx.com/jsfiddle-dojo-require.js"></script>


<body class="claro">
  <div data-dojo-type="dojox.layout.TableContainer" data-dojo-props="cols:6, customClass:'labelsAndValues'" id="tc1">
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit.form.TextBox" title="First Name:" colspan="2" value="Tom"></div>
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit.form.TextBox" title="Last Name:" colspan="2" value="Clarke"></div>
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit.form.TextBox" title="Age:" colspan="2" value="35"></div>
    <textarea data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Textarea" id="texteditor" style="width:100%;" colspan="4" title="Personal Details">Hi, I'm a hacker, I have no personal details to speak of, but I can write a widget in under a minute!</textarea>
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit.form.CheckBox" colspan="2" title="Employed"></div>
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit.form.CheckBox" colspan="2" title="Is Married"></div>
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit.form.CheckBox" colspan="2" title="Has Children"></div>
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit.form.CheckBox" title="Loves Dojo" colspan="2" checked="true"></div>
  </div>
```

UPDATE: it can be applied also with dojo programatically generated content with an observation, the property should be written as `colSpan`:

```js
var tbl = document.getElementById("mytable");
var lastRow = tbl.rows.length;
var row = tbl.insertRow(lastRow);
row.style.backgroundColor = 'aliceblue';
var folioCell = row.insertCell(0);
var textnode = document.createTextNode("hello");

folioCell.appendChild(textnode);
folioCell.colSpan = 2;

var cell = document.getElementById("tomodify");
cell.colSpan = 2;
```

```html
<script type='text/javascript' src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js' data-dojo-config="parseOnLoad:true, async:'legacyAsync'"></script>
<table id="mytable" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>One</td>
    <td>Two</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="tomodify">1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think you missed the fact that I am creating the table programmatically.  If you can help me figure out how to access the DOM, I can easily set the colspan.  The problem is that I can't find the element to alter.

Comment: I'm sorry, I dind't notice you were generating the html from js. So I updated the code with an edition if this is what you need please consider accept my answer.